# Handle any type of quotes in php xpath attribute

Tags: php, xpath

Code:

```php
$items = $stuff->xpath(sprintf('.//item[name="%s"]', $itemName)
```

I have no control over `$itemName` and `$stuff` in any way. Both can contain values with any type of quotes:

```
tes't
tes"t
tes`t
```

How can I change the xpath expression to allow all types of quotes without braking the other quote types.

Comment: Is `addslashes()` what you are looking for? [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
$items = $stuff->xpath(sprintf('.//item[name="%s"]', addslashes($itemName))
```

This will at least take care of the two first quote types:

```
tes't --> tes\'t
tes"t --> tes\"t
tes`t --> tes`t (this is not treated as a quote I guess)
```

To return to original string you can use the `stripslashes()` function

Comment: xpath predicate values do not allow escaped quotes unfortunately.